# Why workflow gem requires sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Trying to make Rails app as light weight as possible with Gem Dependencies.

Interested in using https://github.com/geekq/workflow.  If I am already using MySQL2 or PG, why would I need to install sqlite3 as well?

If not needed, is there a way to override this dependency or do I have to clone it and change this locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only a [development dependency](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring_dependencies) for anyone who wants to work on the gem itself. Most likely, `sqlite3` is required for the database tests.

Just installing/bundling the gem like normal should never install `sqlite3` unless you do `gem install --dev workflow`.